# Why passport.serializeUser() method is called two times when user logs

Tags: express, authentication, serialization, passport.js, express-session

I am using passport & express-session to implement local strategy authentication by session and cookie, but can't able to identify one issue.

When the user logs in, the `passport.serializeUser` method is getting called two times. According to my knowledge, `passport.serializeUser` method should be getting called after authentication done by `passport.authenticate("local")` method, and then the data to be saved in session is decided (here it is `user.id`), and then the session is started for user, and he is redirected to `'/secrets'` route.

I tried console logging user in `passport.serializeUser` and

1. first time `passport.serializeUser` method is executed after `req.login` and
2. second time it is executed after `passport.authenticate("local")` method

Log In code:

```
app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
    const user = new User({
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    req.login(user, (err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/login");
        }
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,()=>{
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

`passport.serializeUser` method code:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(user);   
    done(null, user.id);
});
```

Can somebody explain about this behavior?